# Is "British" a noun or an adjective in "British PM"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

While reading through [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/124808/25030) another occurred to me. If a headline reads

> British PM says no to inflatable cars.

Is *British* a noun or an adjective? Granted, there are other noun forms of British but how about *French* in

> French PM says yes!

The example from the original question quoted

> Yemen PM Escapes Assassination

Since the adjective for the people of Yemen is *Yemeni*, this is clearly a noun adjunct. However, in those cases where the noun and the adjective forms are the same (British, French, Greek, Italian etc.) as in the example above, are these adjectives or nouns? They can be taken as either.

Comment: You seem to be kind of looking at this ‘upside down’, as it were. The nouns and adjectives are _not_ the same for ‘British’, ‘French’, ‘Greek’, ‘Italian’, any more than they are for ‘Yemeni’. The noun is the name of the country (Yemen, Great Britain, France, Greece, Italy), and the adjective is the derived form. _All_ these adjectives can be turned into nouns _if necessary_—that goes for ‘Yemeni’, too: “The Yemeni are a proud people with an overwhelming tendency towards sand in their shoes”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just headliner confusion.  *British* is virtually always an adjective, not a noun.  The noun is *Britain*. But headlines of late have been using the shorter noun forms, as in *Spain court* in lieu of *Spanish court*.  I wouldn’t recommend it outside of headlines, if even there.

Be that as it may, we aren’t going to start calling *British, French, German, Spanish, Chinese,* or *Japanese* “nouns” just because their corresponding noun forms are now getting used as noun-adjuncts in headline English.

One example of *British* as a noun might be:

> We haven’t seen many **British** around here lately.

Although another is:

> We haven’t seen many **Britishers** around here lately.

Neither of those is particularly well thought of. In writing, *Briton* is usually preferred:

> We haven’t seen many **Britons** around here lately.

But that can of course be misheard in speech as:

> We haven’t seen many ***Britains** around here lately.

Which is one reason why it tends to be shorted to the casual:

> We haven’t seen many **Brits** around here lately.

Comment: That's my point. Since the word can be either and we agree that _Yemen_ in _Yemen PM_ is a noun, why is _British_ an adjective in _British PM_? Perhaps _British_ was not the best example, consider _French PM_ where there is no alternative noun form.

Comment: Because _all_ adjectives can be nominalised. ‘British’ is no different there. It only becomes a noun when we force it to; i.e., when we give it nothing to modify. Here, it modifies something, and there is no reason to assume that an adjective has been nominalised only to be used as a noun adjunct. Occam’s razor would have a word or two to say about that, at least.

Comment: @terdon We aren’t going to start calling *British, French, German, Spanish, Chinese,* or *Japanese* “nouns” just because their corresponding noun forms are now getting used as noun-adjuncts in headline English.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet both you and tchrist make good points. Yet the dictionary [does](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Greek) list these as nouns. Still, I think you're right and I'm nit-picking, Occam's razor applies. Thank you both.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You've probably deduced that I'm a mismatcher by now. Accepting _mere_ and _sheer_ as adjectives, ...

Comment: 'The British are fond of their tea' is quite acceptable.

Comment: ...so is "The British are not cheese-eating surrender monkeys", despite what all the headlines seem to be saying about us just because we don't want to get dragged into [pointlessly?] bombing Syria.

Comment: (1) You say "The noun is *Britain*". Actually the noun is ***Great Britain*** or the ***United Kingdom*** (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Britain). (2) ***Britisher*** is not actually used by the British. It's given as AmE or old-fashioned BrE (http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=Britisher&title=21st, http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/Britisher?q=britisher). (3) ***Briton*** is rarely used in BrE except in the context of *ancient Briton* (Celtic people living in S.Britain before/during Roman times) (http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=Briton&title=21st).

Comment: @TrevorD Briton, in the sense of a contemporary British person, may not be used as frequently as it used to be but it is still encountered fairly frequently in British English.  It should also be noted that there is a difference between Great Britain and the United Kingdom.  Strictly speaking, Great Britain refers to the main island (most of England, Scotland and Wales), though in common usage it refers to the entirety of England, Wales and Scotland which all contain some smaller islands.  The United Kingdom also encompasses Northern Ireland

Comment: @BrummiePete: Maybe we disagree with how often "Briton" is used in modern BrE: I can't recall when I last encountered it.  I agree that my comment about GB & UK was ambiguous, since, of course, the full name of the UK is "*the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland*": I was merely countering tchrist's statement that "The noun is *Britain*."

Comment: @TrevorD:  I can find a fair few news stories referring to Britons (http://news.sky.com/story/1668659/cyprus-hijack-britons-were-last-to-flee-plane for instance or a BBC article suggesting that "Britons spend more time on tech than asleep" which certainly came as a surprise).  It's definitely less common than it used to be, but it's still in active use.

Comment: @BrummiePete: I stand corrected: maybe I just don't notice it.  I rarely look at Sky, but I do have a vague recollection of seeing that BBC article.  :-(